# Overide CSS Class For Form Layout

Tags: css, forms

I am using the CSS shown below to create a properly aligned form without the use of tables. Only problem is that one of the fields has multiple "options" that should be shown right next to it. What style can I append to the items I want next to a specific field to make sure that they don't display as "inline-block"?

```css
label {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 180px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

input {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 165px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question? perhaps with a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) example. What do you mean by "options"?

Comment: Just add an extra class to the field w/ multiple options so that it doesn't display inline-block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the items an id.

Ids take precedence over general element or class statements as they are more specific.  For example, you could wrap the items in a div with `id="myItems"` and then add the following css rule after the rules above:

```
input#myItems {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're asking... maybe along the lines of this?

If you want to override a CSS stylization for a specific element, you can use the **`!important`** declaration.

Example:

```
li {
    background-color: #000;
}

/*A specific list to have a white background*/

.specific {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

The `!important` tag will override all other stylizations/inherits.  http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/